# Pinning arrays of structs that contain un-blitable types c#

Tags: c#, memory-management, struct

I have a scenario where there are arrays of structs and I am building batches of them (i.e StructA, StructB, StructD) in an object with pointers to their memory (as the struct data could be updated after the batch has been created) and I don't want to have to track that and rebuild the batch, ideally I want to contain all the pointers for quick lookup.

So for example here is what one of the batches looks like:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct Batch<T1, T2> : IEquatable<Batch<T1, T2>> 
    where T1 : unmanaged, IComponent
    where T2 : unmanaged, IComponent
{
    public readonly int EntityId;
    public readonly T1* Component1;
    public readonly T2* Component2;

    public Batch(int entityId, T1* component1, T2* component2)
    {
        EntityId = entityId;
        Component1 = component1;
        Component2 = component2;
    }
}
```

Now originally I just used `fixed` keyword and looped over the arrays taking the structs I wanted and getting their address, however I quickly realised that fixing only works within the scope of the method so the GC will still move memory around which meant after a time the pointers would reference garbage.

So then I looked into pinning the memory, however when I do this it blows up if the structs contain bools (and I think `chars`, basically any structs that are not blittable). In this scenario all structs should contain value type data, however I do not want to have to enforce blittable data types if possible to avoid.

So as `fixed` is only temporary, and pinning only allows blittable data, is there another approach which would allow me to get pointers/references to the structs?

The main motivation for doing this batching was performance as it would ideally keep memory access sequential and hopefully allow more pre-fetching and caching on the CPU, so this is why we are keeping pointers rather than just having an index to lookup (As that would potentially ruin any prefetching and cache lookups).

== Edit ==

Just for clarity the framework in question is a .net standard class library which is *currently* built against .net standard 2.1.

It also is targetting c# 7.3, I am not entirely sure if I am safe to move to c# 8.0 as the consumers may be running on .net framework or mono, so if they are stuck on 7.3 then may need to confirm this before I could upgrade.

Comment: .net framework? .net core?

Comment: Applies to either, the framework in question is .net standard so can be run on either platform.

Comment: Which version of .net standard? The tools available to you change depending on what exactly you're targetting?

Comment: Will update with details

Comment: [Related](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1147).